# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - with converting series month name to month num

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe, `df['Month']`, that has month names: January, February, etc.

I want to convert these to month numbers: 1, 2, etc.

In my Pandas, `df['Month_Num'] = list(cal.month_abbr).index(df['Month'])` throws error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar as cal

df['Day'] = 1
# convert 'January' to 1
df['Month_Num'] = list(cal.month_abbr).index(df['Month'])
df['date_tw'] = ''
# Create date_time based on format `mm/dd/yy`:
df['date_tw'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Month_Num', 'Day', 'Year']])

result_df = df
```

Why is this occurring? The only data I could find on it was [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) related to comparison operators, which mine is not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a slightly different approach with `map`/`replace` instead;

```
mapping = {v : k for k, v in enumerate(cal.month_abbr)}
df['Month_Num'] = df['Month'].map(mapping)
```

For columns with full month names, use `cal.month_name` instead.

Comment: in my `Month_Num` column, this gets me `5.0` for `May` only, and the rest are `null`. I'm assuming that's because `month_abbr` accepts abbreviations, whereas my `month` col are full months `January, February, etc`. Calendar doesn't seem to offer support for full months?

Comment: @Growler Ah, you'll want `cal.month_name` instead.

Comment: Great this works. 

One more thing, I'm getting `ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [month] is missing` when I do `df['date_tw'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Month_Num', 'Day', 'Year']])` — It looks like pandas expects `Year, Month Day`, so I tried that and still get the same error. I checked debugger and `Month_Num` is there with no nulls.

Comment: @Growler You may want to try `pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month_Num', 'Day']])` instead.